# Compact $G$-ENR's and Euler characteristic computed with Alexander-Spanier cohomology with compact support

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, lie-groups, differential-topology, cohomology, euler-characteristics

Let $(Z,A)$ a compact ENR pair, then
$$\chi(Z)=\chi_c(Z-A)+\chi(A)$$
where $\chi_c$ is the Euler characteristic taken in Alexander-Spanier cohomology with compact support (ENR means euclidean neighborhood retract).
According to the book [*Transformation Groups*](https://books.google.com.mx/books?id=azcQhi6XeioC&printsec=frontcover&hl=es&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Tammo tom Dieck, page 230, proposition 1.12
$$\chi(X^{K}/NK)=\displaystyle\sum_{(H_i)}{\chi_c(X^{K}_{(H_i)}/NK)}$$
where $X$ is a compact $G$-ENR, with $G$ a compact Lie group, $K$ is a (closed?) subgroup of $G$ and $H_i$'s run through a complete set of conjugacy classes of (closed?) subgroups of $G$.
Each $X^{K}_{(H_i)}/NK$ is supposed to be a subtraction $X_i-Y_i$ where $(X_i,Y_i)$ is a compact ENR pair, but I do not see what that spaces are. Any suggestion?, please. Do $K$ and each $H_i$ need to be closed?.